# Removing newlines from ob_get_clean() output

Tags: php, output-buffering

ok i do have this following codes

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
codepad is an 
online compiler/interpreter, 
and a simple collaboration tool.
Paste 

your code below, 
and codepad wi
ll run 
it and give you a short 
URL you can use to share
 it in chat or email
<?php
$str = str_replace('\r\n','',trim(ob_get_clean()));
echo $str;
?>
```

and you can see how it works here
http://codepad.org/DrOmyoY9

now what i want here **is to remove the newlines from the stored output** of the `ob_get_clean()`.

I almost looked around the internet on how to remove newlines in the strings and that's the common and fastest method to remove the newlines aside from using the slowly `preg_replace()`.

Why this happens? is this already a bug? or i just missed something?

Comment: \r\n is windows style. what if user using linux \n? best array("\r","\n")

Comment: @Dreadedsemicolon please post your answer i gonna accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\r\n is windows style, but if the user using linux or mac, it would be different . so best solution is:

```
$str = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),'',trim(ob_get_clean()));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think u miss one thing, it should be :

```
$str = str_replace("\r\n",'',trim(ob_get_clean()));
```

using double quotes not single quotes

Comment: well yeah i added "\t" on it but i make it in an array as said as one of the commentator of my question